# Finding optimal parameter values using a Bayesian model

Tags: bayesian, inference

I have a problem with the following setup.  I've been reading ["Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: A Tutorial with R and BUGS"](http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/) and it seems like the Bayesian approach is a good one, but I'm not entirely sure how to model it.

I've got roughly 20 events that I'd like to analyze.  Each event should be similar, and I can apply the same analysis to each.  I'll assume that the events are independent (they might not be, but I'm not worried about that).  For each event, I have a function of three parameters: threshold, s, and t.  Threshold is a continuous variable between 0 and .5, and I'm guessing that the useful values are around .1.  s is an integer between 15 and 2, and t is an integer between s and 1.  I can run the function over all values of s and t and a sample of values for threshold, probably .05, .06, ..., .2 (or whatever, this is flexible).  The function gives me a raw score, where higher is better, and negative values are, well, negative; they represent an actual loss.  It will be straightforward enough to normalize the raw score to a value between 1 and -1.

What I want to know is what are the best values for the parameters (or, technically the distributions of the parameters) that will lead to the best(ish) score(s), after looking at all the events.  What I'm thinking I'll do is the following:

Model threshold as a normal-like variable - using either a normal distribution, or beta, or gamma.  I'm leaning towards a beta or gamma distribution because it is fairly easy to model my high uncertainty about the prior, and I don't expect the distribution to be perfectly bell-shaped, or even symmetric.

Similarly, model s and t as normal-like distributions (again, leaning towards beta or gamma, for the same reasons).  Even though the values are integers, it's no big deal at the end of the day if the mean of the posterior distribution is, say 8.6 - I can work with that.  If there were distributions that handled discrete values, that would be cool, but, again, not necessary.  I realize the binomial distribution is discrete, but it's more about modelling binary outcomes, if my understanding is correct, so I'm going to steer away from it in this particular instance.

My question is, how do I utilize the score, either in raw form (guessing not that useful) or the normalized form (hopefully useful)?  It seems like the most important piece of information, but I don't know how to incorporate it.  I'm not trying to build a regression model; I'm looking more for the optimal results.  And I don't want to do a logistic regression; again, it's not a prediction, but also because it's not a simple yes or no - best score or not - I want to weight parameters that give a normalized score of say .98 nearly as high as the ones that produce a 1.

If I were doing this without Bayesian analysis, I think what I would do is something like, for each data point, for each parameter, add a value equal to normalized score for that data point.  Then, at the end, look at, say, the top 3 or 5 values for each parameter, and try to make a decision based on that.

But I'd like to understand how to model this in a Bayesian way.  Any advice appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me make sure I have this right: You have a function $f(threshold, s, t)$ that you'd like to maximize, is that right? Also, which variables are actually observed in your data?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially correct.  The function actually works on a much larger data set; none of those three are observed, so I guess you could really say it's a function _f(threshold, s, t, d)_ where _d_ is the largish multi-dimensional data set for each of the 20 or so events.  It's essentially a backtesting strategy, and those three variables represent things that I have control over.  The function _f_ transforms everything into a single, useful meaningful number, and that is what I want to maximize.

Comment: Hmm, without knowing more about the problem, I'm having trouble seeing a well-suited Bayesian approach. It sounds like more of an optimization problem. Is your function differentiable with respect to $threshold, s,$ and $t$? If so, you could probably solve for the maximizing parameters using gradient descent or BFGS by minimizing $-f$.

Comment: It's not a function per say, it's a whole program to calculate the particular values given the inputs.  I think what I really want to know is how to weight a piece of evidence in a Bayesian model, i.e. "Here is a piece of evidence (or piece of data), but I think it's only 15% credible (or 82% or whatever), so only take it into account that much", and where every piece of evidence has it's own weight.  So, ignoring the above example briefly, if you had a series of observations, but you believed that older ones were less relevant than newer ones, so you wanted to weight them appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, thinking about this a little more, _f_ isn't a function in the mathematical sense - it has noise, the same inputs give different results over time, etc.  So _f_ is more just a way to summarize all the information of a particular event.  I'm thinking maybe I should rewrite this question (or ask a new one) that is much simpler...

Comment: If a revision might give more detail on the structure of the problem, then it might help find an appropriate answer. To your weighting question, if it's a strictly time-based approach, you might weight older data with an decaying exponential smoothing function, and model its parameter based on your data.

Comment: If nothing else, I could suggest distributions to use for your parameters, might that be helpful?

Comment: Anything would be appreciated, it's all a learning experience :)  The exponential for time makes sense for the time parameter itself, but how do you combine it with the other parameter(s)?  Simple multiplication itself doesn't quite give the correct results...

Comment: As a first step in selecting your distributions, think of the support of the probability distribution; meaning, you want to limit your options of distributions to those that produce values in the proper set. For example, $threshold$ is continuous on [0, 0.5], so a uniform or scaled beta might be appropriate. Since $s$ is discrete, a discrete uniform on $(2...15)$ might be a good starting point. To the time question, I'm still not sure I grasp the relationships in your model well enough to give a meaningful answer. Can you revise to include a bit more on how values feed into $f$?